# Can AutHotKey get data from an SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, automation, autohotkey

I am just looking into AutoHotKey for a project I'm working on, and am wondering if it is able to retrieve data from an SQL DB and then use this data while going through a desktop application.

Comment: At best you could have a saved query or something that gets the data.  Then with AutoHotKey you could run the query, save the data to the clipboard, and maybe paste it into the desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use DBA by IsNull

Its an object oriented wrapper around several different databases/database providers

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/71179-ahk-l-dba-16-oop-sql-database-sqlite-mysql-ado/

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, ill have a look